# XPath index value iteration

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
            get_div1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[1]")
            get_div2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[2]")
            get_div3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[3]")
            get_div4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[4]")
.
.
.
.
.
```

I am new to Python-Selenium. I get my required output when I use the Indexes... I am not sure at which Index i get my output so How can I iterate this? Since, I am finding difficulty to assign this //div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[4] to a variable and manipulate. and I do not know how many indexes are available in that web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the elements matching this locator into list and then iterate over the list, something like this:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode']")
for element in elements:
    #do what you need here, like this
    print(element.text)
```